# Debugging user provider jar inside Keycloak server

Tags: authentication, wildfly, keycloak, remote-debugging

I am using keycloak to authenticate users in my application. The users are imported in Keycloak through a external mysql user store. I am placing the user-provider jar inside /standalone/deployments folder.
I need to remotely debug this jar file through intellij.
I tried to uncomment the *JPDA settings for remote socket debugging* in standalone.conf file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following environment variables

- DEBUG_PORT="*:8787"
- DEBUG_MODE=true

and then start the server with `--debug` flag. You should then be able to attach a remote debugger to port `8787`